# Amazon ECS - Permission denied when using IAM role on Docker entrypoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs, aws-parameter-store

I'm looking for a way to inject secrets/certificates into Amazon ECS containers. In my case, it's a simple nginx container.

I've been following this post, using AWS Parameter Store:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-secrets-for-amazon-ecs-applications-using-parameter-store-and-iam-roles-for-tasks/

**Here's the basic gist:**

1. On my Dockerfile, I attach a script on **entrypoint** which installs the AWS client and fetches the keys from AWS parameter store.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM nginx:1.16.0

...
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/run/fetch.sh", "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

*fetch.sh*

```
        aws ssm get-parameter \
            --name ${key} \
            --with-decryption \
            --region us-east-1 \
            --output text \
            --query Parameter.Value
```

2. The task definition assumes an IAM role that has access to the required services (kms + parameter store). I can verify this works because if I ssh to the server and run the script on the container, I am able to fetch the keys from Parameter Store.

```
  {
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "hostPort": 0,
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "containerPort": 443
      }
    ],
    "cpu": 0,
    "environment": [],
    "mountPoints": [],
    "memoryReservation": 256,
    "memory": 512,
    "volumesFrom": [],
    "image": "url/some_image:latest",
    "essential": true,
    "name": "my-container"
  }
```

3. When ECS runs this task, it should hit the **entrypoint** which fetches the keys from parameter store and saves them.

I'm able to fetch the keys on a running task by running it manually via docker exec, but I'm unable to fetch them when starting a task (specifically when I attach the script on the entrypoint as on code above).

Does an ECS task have access to IAM roles at the entrypoint? When does it actually assume IAM roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now easily inject secrets from SSM or Secrets Manager using the `secrets` in the `containerDefinitions` of a task definition. With this solution, you don't have to run/manage your custom scripts to fetch your secrets anymore.

It looks like this:

```json
{
    "containerDefinitions": [{
        "secrets": [{
            "name": "environment_variable_name",
            "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:aws_account_id:secret:secret_name-AbCdEf"
        }]
    }]
}
```

```json
{
    "containerDefinitions": [{
        "secrets": [{
            "name": "environment_variable_name",
            "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:region:aws_account_id:parameter/parameter_name"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Have a look at [AWS Launches Secrets Support for Amazon Elastic Container Service](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aws-launches-secrets-support-for-amazon-elastic-container-servic/) and [Specifying Sensitive Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html).

You must have a task execution role and reference it in your task definition. Example policy:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ssm:GetParameters",
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ssm:<region>:<aws_account_id>:parameter/parameter_name",
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<aws_account_id>:secret:secret_name",
        "arn:aws:kms:<region>:<aws_account_id>:key/key_id"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

More info in [Required IAM Permissions for Amazon ECS Secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html#secrets-iam).

Comment: I've given this a try and somehow adding the task execution role (with all the perms) gives me an error when pulling my ECR image on the task definition: `CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied`. I'm not sure why this is the case because it seems unrelated. I've verified though that removing the task execution role fixes my ECR issue. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a great answer so I'll mark it as accepted. Moving my question to another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965007/getting-cannotpullcontainererror-when-using-ecs-secrets