# How do I change my IAM ECSTaskExecutionRole to give me permission to get parameters from Systems Manager - Parameter Store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-ssm

I want to pass secrets or sensitive information securely to containers in a task for Amazon Elastic Container Service (Amazon ECS). I have a Docker container on ECS and a Task Definition that pulls environment variables from Systems Parameter Store. However, when I run my task in ECS, I get the following error message when I try to run my container.

> STOPPED (Fetching secret data from SSM Parameter Store in us-east-2:
> AccessDeniedException: User:
> arn:was:sts::<my_account_id>:assumed-role/ecsTaskExecutionRole/2c0dfb5f086da28abc753c07b6de728 is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameters on resource:
> arn:was:ssm:us-east-2:<my_account_id>:parameter/<MY_PARAMETER> status
> code: 400, request id: <request_id>

https://gyazo.com/5a3dd8c06da3614d19b8bc725e572f2c

I followed this article on passing sensitive information to containers in an ECS task.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-data-security-container-task/

Per the article, I went into IAM and added the following in-line policy to my ecsTaskExecutionRole.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "ssm:GetParameters"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:secret:SLACK_API_TOKEN*",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:secret:DB_USER*",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:secret:DB_PASSWORD*",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:secret:DB_HOST*",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:secret:DB_DATABASE_NAME*",
                "arn:aws:ssm:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:parameter/SLACK_API_TOKEN",
                "arn:aws:ssm:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:parameter/DB_USER",
                "arn:aws:ssm:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:parameter/DB_PASSWORD",
                "arn:aws:ssm:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:parameter/DB_HOST",
                "arn:aws:ssm:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:parameter/DB_DATABASE_NAME",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have an AWS Managed Policy that looks like this under the same ecsTaskExecutionRole.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The full IAM role for ecsTaskExecutionRole looks like this:

https://gyazo.com/b28a4ae1beca4db31228298767685fe2

The keys in the Parameter Store are stored as Secret Strings. I'm not using my own keys and just using whatever the default one is for my account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by looking at

[Amazon ECS - Permission denied when using IAM role on Docker entrypoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948173/amazon-ecs-permission-denied-when-using-iam-role-on-docker-entrypoint)

Since I was encrypting the parameters in SSM using AWS' default KMS, I needed to give permissions to KMS in my in-line policy in my ecsExecuteTask role. I also needed to get rid of the line that says "Sid": "VisualEditor0". I'm not sure how that got in there.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:secret:SLACK_API_TOKEN*",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:secret:DB_USER*",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:secret:DB_PASSWORD*",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:secret:DB_HOST*",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:secret:DB_DATABASE_NAME*",
                "arn:aws:ssm:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:parameter/SLACK_API_TOKEN",
                "arn:aws:ssm:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:parameter/DB_USER",
                "arn:aws:ssm:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:parameter/DB_PASSWORD",
                "arn:aws:ssm:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:parameter/DB_HOST",
                "arn:aws:ssm:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:parameter/DB_DATABASE_NAME",
                "arn:aws:km:<my_region>:<my_account_id>:key/<my_key>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This completely resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to pass those sensitive information to the containers would be to inject them via environment variable at container startup.

Define `secrets` key in the task definition, and provide arn of those variables in `valueFrom`. See the example below:

```
{
  "volumes": [],
  "family": "example-tasks",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/example-tasks",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 5000,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 5000
        }
      ],
      "cpu": 0,
      "memoryReservation": 512,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "image": "123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/example:latest",
      "name": "example-container",
      "environmentFiles": [
        {
            "value": "arn:aws:s3:::s3_example_bucket/s3_example.env",
            "type": "s3"
        }
      ],
      "secrets": [
        {
          "name": "SECRET_1",
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:123456789012:parameter/SECRET_1"
        },
        {
          "name": "SECRET_2",
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:123456789012:parameter/SECRET_2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```